# How to alter dynamic/live element attributes - (replaceWith()) used

Tags: jquery, dynamic, replace, live

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to access and alter attributes of HTML content added in place of a placeholder element using replaceWith.

Here is the scenario:

Here is the HTML (kept in a php file) that replaces the '#null_item' element in the subsequent HTML table:

```html
<tr id="sign_options">
 <td>
  <input class="finalSign" type="hidden" value="" name="item_name_1" />
  <figure class="sample">
   <a id="sign_preview_lightbox" href="" rel="lightbox" title="Sign preview">
    <img id="sign_preview" src="/signs/previews/basic_aluminium_spacer4_f.jpg" alt="Sign preview" title="Sign preview" />
   </a>
  </figure>
 </td>
</tr>
```

```js
if(localStorage['cartItem']) {
  $.get("/cart.php", function(data) {
    $('#null_item').replaceWith($(data));//fix this 'replaceWith' kak!
  });
}

console.log(signPreview);
console.log(document.getElementById('sign_preview').src);
```

```html
<table id="quote">
  <colgroup>
    <col id="sign_col" span="1"><col id="options_col" span="1"><col id="qty_col" span="1"><col id="price_col" span="1"><col id="total_col" span="1">
  </colgroup>
  <th>Sign</th><th>Options</th><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th>

  <tr id="null_item"><td><span class="italic">Empty</span></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td id="delivery" class="subtotal">S$0</td></tr>
  <tr id="totals"><td></td><td></td><td colspan="2"><span class="boxed">Total signs</span></td><td>S$0</td></tr>
  <tr id="totals"><td></td><td></td><td colspan="2"><span class="boxed">Delivery</span></td><td>S$0</td></tr>
  <tr id="totals"><td></td><td></td><td colspan="2"><span class="boxed">Installation</span></td><td>S$0</td></tr>
  <tr id="discount"><td colspan="2">Discount code <input maxlength="7" class="discountCode" value="" onchange="calculateTotals()" name="discount_code"></td><td colspan="2"><span class="boxed">Discount</span></td><td>-S$0</td></tr>
  <tr id="grand_total"><td></td><td></td><td colspan="2"><span class="boxed">Grand total</span></td><td>S$0</td></tr>
  <tr id="buy_row"><td colspan="4"><img id="secure" src="/img/payment.png" alt="Secure payment via Paypal" title="Secure payment via Paypal"></td><td><input id="buy_now" class="buy_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="BUY NOW" alt="PayPal . The safer, easier way to pay online." onclick="paypalPasser()" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

The first block of HTML successfully replaces the intended '#null_item' tr, but after that, I cannot replace the scr for the '#sign_preview" img, nor can I read any existing src link.

Can anyone shed light? I know that for events one has to use the .on function and target the new element, but I don't know how to use that method to alter attributes of dynamically loaded elements.

Comment: As a side note, your HTML markup is not valid, IDs must be unqiue on document context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing you're maybe not wrapping your head around is the idea of callbacks and asynchronous methods.

You're currently running your `console.log` statements *before* the `replaceWith` occurs.

The `function() { }` block (your "callback") passed as the second parameter to `$.get` doesn't execute until the AJAX call to the server completes; the rest of your code following the call to `$.get` continues to run immediately.

Try this, to see the effect:

```
console.log('About to $.get');
if(localStorage['cartItem']) {
  console.log('$.get()ing...');
  $.get("/cart.php", function(data) {
    $('#null_item').replaceWith($(data));//fix this 'replaceWith' kak!
    console.log('$got!');
    console.log(document.getElementById('sign_preview').src);
  });
}
console.log('After $.get()');
```

The output will be:

```
About to $.get
$.get()ing...
After $.get()
...
$got!
<the value of .src>
```

So basically, you were trying to access an element before it existed. If you want to run code as a result of the AJAX method, it should be in, or called from, the callback.

Here's how I would rewrite it:

```
$.get("/cart.php").done(function(data) { 
    $('#null_item').replaceWith(data);
    // further processing
}).fail(function(xhr, status, message) { 
    // handle failures
    alert('Ouch, an error occurred! ' + message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cory, your comment pointed me in the right direction, and I solve the issue using the .done() callback function for .get():

```js
 if(localStorage['cartItem']) {
  $.get("/cart.php", function(data) {
   document.getElementById('null_item').outerHTML = data;
   //$('#null_item').replaceWith($(data));//fix this 'replaceWith' kak!
   //$('#null_item').remove();
  })
   .done(function() {
    //Assign cart object key-values to table row elements
    var parsedCartItem = JSON.parse(localStorage['cartItem2']);
    var signPreview = parsedCartItem.Sign.Front;
    
    console.log(signPreview);
    console.log(document.getElementById('sign_preview').src);
    
    $('#sign_preview_lightbox').attr('href', signPreview);
    $('#sign_preview').attr('src', signPreview);
   });
 }
```

Comment: FYI, both the `function (data) { ... }` and the `.done()` function will be called when the `$.get` completes. I would suggest moving your `.outerHTML` assignment line into `.done()` and omit the second parameter to `$.get` altogether. The same parameters are passed to each, so you just have to add the `data` parameter to the function in `.done()`. E.g. `$.get("/cart.php").done(function(data) { ... }).fail(function() { /* ouch! */ });`

Comment: I edited my answer with a code snippet illustrating my thoughts.